# Javascript confirm with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

Hi Here is my code to display the alert box:

```
    var answer = window.confirm ("The registration you have entered is illegal for the uk roads. By clicking ok you are accepting full resposibility for this plate and agreeing to use it for offroad use only.");

    if (answer) {
    //Tell them its a show plate
    $('#numberplateyellow').append(platetext);
    $('#numberplatewhite').append(platetext); 
    $('#illegal').append('Show Plate Not Road Legal');
    }else{
    $('#illegal').empty();
    }

  }else{
     //Its A Legal Plate
    $('#numberplateyellow').append(platetext);
    $('#numberplatewhite').append(platetext);  
  }
```

I wish for the windows.confirm to contain a checkbox that says check here if you agree to the terms and conditions.

How do i add a checkbox to the window.confirm ?

Thanks

Comment: What js library are you using? jQuery?

Comment: Also your if/elses dont match up at all

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add a checkbox to a confirm. You will have to make your own dialog for that to work.

---

Here is a fiddle demo using jQuery's dialog: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/tRBEt/

Comment: I have seen this on some sites but i dont have the URL no more, so how would i get around this

Comment: @user, you can try using jQuery's dialog. im makeing a fiddle demo for you now

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit default window feature, so there is no way you can add a checkbox in confirm or alert.

So what's the solution:

Implement your own: you may user intercept submit, create a modal pop that contains checkbox etc, whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an alert style box generated in the browser (which is unlikely to support checkbox's unless their is a proprietary browswer way of doing it).... You may wish to consider a modal dialog box as it will give you more control.

A good implementation is jQuery-UI's dialog box: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/